# Algorithm for generating huge wordlist

Tags: algorithm, md5, permutation

Alright, I know this is going to sound bad, like I'm going to use this for un-ethical things, but you have my word that I am not.

I am writing a paper for my Computer and Information Security course and the topic I chose was hashing methods. One of the points that I go over in my paper is MD5 being only one-way and the only way to crack an MD5 hash is to continuously make strings and use an MD5 function, then compare it with the hash you want to crack.

I would like to build a really simple mock-up program to show alongside my paper (we do a presentation and this would be an awesome thing to have), so I wanted to work out an algorithm that makes a string with every possible character combination up to 8 characters. For example the output will be:

a, b, c, ..., aa, ab, ac, ... ba, bb, bc etc etc etc.

It need to include letters, numbers and symbols if possible.

I got partly through the algorithm for this, but unfortunately my programming skills are not up to the task. If anyone can provide a complete algorithm for this I'd be extremely thankful.

Again, if you think I'm a liar and I'm going to use this for hacking purposes you don't have to leave an answer.

Thank you. :)

Comment: that would take a very long time to run.

Comment: If you don't know how to do it then maybe you shouldn't pass the class.

Comment: Hi John, I know how long it would take to actually crack an MD5, much longer than the time I have to present my paper! :) But I was thinking of just hashing a string like "abc", so it doesn't take too long to crack but shows how long it could take and how these methods are done. Thanks :)

Comment: NSD: The class isn't about programming. We lightly cover programming later on next year but as of yet we have had no programming tasks set for us. I know how to do this but I just cannot work out the algorithm. Thanks.

Comment: around 272 billion, actually :)

Comment: OP is asking for characters (let's say just lowercase), numbers, and symbols (I count about 29 in ASCII).  That's (26+29+10)^8, about 318 trillion.  Big file.

Comment: @NSD: Aren't you jumping to conclusions? The OP mentions it's for a paper for a computer security class. I don't think he needs to write a program to understand and illustrate the basics of information security.

Comment: that would be for the 26 character alphabet, for numbers and symbols the number would be much higher

Comment: @all: I probably should of stated that this will not be held in a file, if it was I'd need a lot more hard drive space than what the presentation computer has ;). It will simply store the hashes string in a variable, and then every time it goes around the loop replace it with the new one. That way I don't end up with a massive file and it's probably faster. Thanks.

Comment: By *FAR* the slowest aspect of this is going to be to display the info.  Also don't generate them all beforehand--RAM is far smaller than your HD--anything that would fill the HD will have long ago filled the RAM.

Comment: The cool thing about hashing functions is the security of the hash is generally independent of the length of the input.  Cracking "abc" is (in general) as hard as cracking any other MD5, in the abstract.

Answer (score 6):

In Python, [itertools.product](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html?#itertools.product) does almost all you require -- though it does it for just one "number of repeats", so you'll have to iterate from 1 to 8 (not hard;-).  In essence:

```
import itertools
import string

# whatever you wish as alphabet (lower/upper, digits, punct, &c)
myalphabet = string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_digits

def prods(maxlen, alphabet=myalphabet):
  for i in range(1, maxlen+1):
    for s in itertools.product(alphabet, repeat=i):
      yield ''.join(s)
```

Of course, for an alphabet of length N and K repetitions (8 in your case) this does produce N + N^2 + ... + N^K possibilities (2,901,713,047,668 possibilities for N=36 and K=8), but, what's a few trillion outputs among friends!-)

Answer (score 3):

To implement this i would probably encode integers to base 36 (or more if you wanted symbols).

1 = 1
2 = 2
...
a = 10
b = 12
..

and so on.

then you would have a number, like 38 and do some divisions, ie:

38/36 = 1 remaider 2 = 12 in base 36

then just run a for loop to your max number you want to encode, something very large and output your encoded numbers.

just for fun i wrote this for you: http://pastebin.antiyes.com/index.php?id=327

Comment: Ah! This certainly is a interesting way to do it. I'll check back later to see if anyone else comes up with something, but this seems very likely. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

It is not true that "the only way to crack an MD5 hash" is to generate every possible string and look for collisions. In fact, if you have access to the original it is possible to modify it so that its MD5 matches that of another file you can create. This is described in [a paper at infosec.edu](http://www.infosec.sdu.edu.cn/uploadfile/papers/How%20to%20Break%20MD5%20and%20Other%20Hash%20Functions.pdf).

Even if you cannot modify the original file, [rainbow tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) of MD5 checksums exist which can be used to generate collisions.

These facts make MD5 unsuitable for passwords or cryptography, and in fact the U.S. government has forbidden its continued use for secure applications.

Comment: Not true. The vulnerability of MD5 you describe is to a collision attack, which requires both the original and the impostor message to be under the control of an attacker. This makes MD5 unsuitable for some applications but fine for others. MD5 is not at this time known to have any practical preimage attack, which is what is required if you are *given* an arbitrary file not under your control, and you wish to create an impostor plaintext which matches the arbitrary file's MD5 hash. http://www.vpnc.org/hash.html

Comment: Or if you are in fact saying the same thing I am, you should make it clearer. (anyway the paper cited is no longer available online, apparently.)

Comment: That is indeed what I meant, apologies if it was not clear. And I have fixed the URL.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have access to the hashed version of the password, then [MD5 is broken to begin with](http://www.win.tue.nl/hashclash/SoftIntCodeSign/).  That said, when it comes to breaking a hashed value, you'd likely be better off using [Rainbow Tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table), [Dictionary Attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionary_attack), and [Social Engineering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_engineering_%28security%29) over your brute force method.  That said, since you asked for an algorithm to generate all the values, maybe the following will be beneficial (C#):

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace PossibiltyIterator
{
  class Program
  {
    static readonly char[] Symbols = {
      'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 
      'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 
      'I', 'J', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 
      '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', '!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', 
      '*', '(', ')', '-', '_', '+', '=', '/', '\\', '[', ']', '{', '}', ';', ':', '\'', '"', 
      ',', '.', '<', '>', '?', '`', '~'
    };

    const int MaxLength = 8;

    static void BuildWord(int currentLength, int desiredLength, char[] word)
    {
      if (currentLength == desiredLength)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(word);
      }
      else
      {
        for (int value = 0; value < Symbols.Length; ++value)
        {
          word[currentLength] = Symbols[value];
          BuildWord(currentLength + 1, desiredLength, word);
        }
      }
    }

    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
      double totalValues = (Math.Pow(Symbols.Length, MaxLength + 1) - Symbols.Length)/(Symbols.Length - 1);
      Console.WriteLine("Warning! You are about to print: {0} values", totalValues);
      Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
      Console.ReadKey(true /* intercept */);

      for (int desiredLength = 1; desiredLength <= MaxLength; ++desiredLength)
      {
        BuildWord(0 /* currentLength */, desiredLength, new char[MaxLength]);
      }
    }

  }
}
```

To be completely honest, this can be optimized further.  Because it builds all the "words" of length 1, then does that work a second time in building the words of length 2.  It would be smarter to build the words of length MaxLength, then truncate one letter to build a word of MaxLength-1.

Here is the optimized version... note that it does NOT return the words in the order originally requested.

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace PossibiltyIterator
{
  class Program
  {
    static readonly char[] Symbols = {
      'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 
      'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 
      'I', 'J', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 
      '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', '!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', 
      '*', '(', ')', '-', '_', '+', '=', '/', '\\', '[', ']', '{', '}', ';', ':', '\'', '"', 
      ',', '.', '<', '>', '?', '`', '~'
    };

    const int MaxLength = 8;

    static void BuildWord(int currentLength, int desiredLength, char[] word)
    {
      if (currentLength != desiredLength)
      {
        for (int value = 0; value < Symbols.Length; ++value)
        {
          word[currentLength] = Symbols[value];
          BuildWord(currentLength + 1, desiredLength, word);
        }
        word[currentLength] = '\0';
      }

      Console.WriteLine(word);
    }

    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
      double totalValues = (Math.Pow(Symbols.Length, MaxLength + 1) - Symbols.Length)/(Symbols.Length - 1);
      char[] word = new char[MaxLength];

      Console.WriteLine("Warning! You are about to print: {0} values", totalValues);
      Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
      Console.ReadKey(true /* intercept */);

      BuildWord(0 /* currentLength */, MaxLength, new char[MaxLength]);
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: The recursive stack should never exceed MaxLength (well maybe MaxLength+1), so that would be unlikely.

Comment: Your comment about "MD5 is broken to begin with" is incorrect. Attacks on MD5 are collision attacks, not preimage attacks, and require an attacker to create both of the plaintext documents. See first paragraph of the "Vulnerability analysis" of the webpage you cite, or see http://vpnc.org/hash.html

Comment: I stand by what I said, especially given what was posted by @Dour High Arch.  "if you have access to the original it is possible to modify it so that its MD5 matches that of an arbitary file. This is described in a paper at infosec.edu."

Answer (score 0):

To complete the post with a Java example which will print out the Base64 encoded MD5's of all possible character combinations using only 0-9 and a-z characters:

```
MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
int i = 0;
while (true)
{
    String raw = Integer.toString(i, Character.MAX_RADIX);
    byte[] md5 = digest.digest(raw.getBytes());
    String base64 = new BigInteger(1, md5).toString(16);
    System.out.println(raw + " = " + base64);
    i++;
}
```